# Count permutations of [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] with length 6

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How can I count number of permutations such as:

`[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`
`[1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]`
`[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5]`
...

So I have:

'1' x 3
'2' x 2
'3' x 2
'4' x 1
'5' x 1

So permutation valid if it contains $\le3$ of '1' and $\le2$ of '2' and and $\le2$ of '3' and $\le1$ of '4' and $\le1$ of '5' and it's length is 6.

I've counted them on Python with filtering and the answer is 3630. But how it works?

Thanks!

Comment: are they all increasing?

Comment: It's just a permutations, order is not matter

Comment: I think you mean combination then

Comment: No, I mean order of sets, not order of elements

Comment: This is not clear.  Are the two lists $[1,1,1,2,2,3]$ and $[2,2,3,1,1,1]$ equivalent or not?

Comment: @lulu I think these two are different. What OP means to say is that the elements need not to be in a particular increasing order. We want total number of ordered pairs of length  $6$

Comment: Oh, I had understood exactly the opposite haha.

Comment: "No, I mean order of sets" this makes 0 sense lol.

Comment: @JaideepKhare  I'd have guessed the opposite meaning.  But why should we guess at all?  The OP should settle the point .

Comment: @lulu The OP has written `order is not matter` for the increasing order. That is true because OP denied for combinations, and said that it is permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have five mutually-exclusive kinds of collections here:

1. Exactly one pair, no three of a kind (like $[1,1,2,3,4,5]$)
2. Exactly two pair, no three of a kind (like $[1,1,2,2,3,4]$)
3. Exactly three pair (like $[1,1,2,2,3,3]$)
4. Three of a kind, no pair (like $[1,1,1,2,3,4]$)
5. Three of a kind, one pair (like $[1,1,1,2,2,3]$)

Case 1: Pick the number for the pair, and the places you put them $(3 \cdot 15)$. Then order the other four numbers in the remaining spaces $(4!)$.

Case 2: Pick the two numbers for the pair ($3$) and place the smaller number in two places $(15)$ then the larger in two of the remaining places $(6)$. Then, choose the remaining two numbers and place them $(6)$.

Case 3: Place the $1$s in two of the spaces $(15)$ and then the $2$s in two of the remaining four $(6)$. (The $3$s go in the spaces that remain.)

Case 4: Place the $1$s $(6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 / (3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1) = 20)$. Choose three numbers out of $2,3,4,5$ and place them ($4 \cdot 6$).

Case 5: Place the $1$s $(20)$. Choose whether the pair is $2$s or $3$s, and place them $(2 \cdot 3)$. Choose the last number and put it in the spot that remains $(3)$.

Adding these up: $1080 + 1620 + 90 + 480 + 360 = 3630$.

*(Hat tip to [N.F. Taussig](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173070/n-f-taussig) for helping me work through the errors!)*

Comment: You made your errors in cases 2, 3, and 5.  In cases 2 and 3, you do not need to divide by 2.  In case 2, after you choose which two numbers will appear twice, choose the positions of the smaller number in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, then choose the positions of the larger number in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  Notice that this does not count the same arrangement twice since only one of the numbers may be the smaller number.  In case 3, choose the positions of the 1's, then the 2's.  In case 5, you have used two of the five digits, leaving you with three choices for the final digit.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Wow, I batted only .400 first time around! Thanks for helping me think through those.

Answer (score 4):

The exponential generating function for the number of permutations of length $r$ is
$$f(x) = (1+x)^2 \left( 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 \right)^2 \left(1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}x^3 \right)$$
On expansion (I used a computer algebra system), the coefficient of $x^6$ is $121/24$, so the number of permutations of length 6 is

> $$\frac{121}{24} \cdot 6! = 3630$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are forced to sum mutually exclusive and exhaustive possibilities.

I suggest defining $N(a,b)$ as the number of permutations having $a$ "1"'s and $b$ other doubles. Then ...
$$N(a,b) = \binom 2 b \cdot \frac{6!}{a!(2!)^b}$$

and
$$ N_{tot} = N(0,2)+N(1,2)+N(1,1)+N(2,2)+N(2,1)+N(2,0)+N(3,1)+N(3,0) $$

*** EDIT ***

I my expression gave the number of permutations given a specific combination of "single" extra numbers (extra means not including 1 or any doubles )

there will be $4-b$ "single" numbers from which we must choose $6-a-2b$
So my formula above should be amended to read

$$N(a,b) =\binom{4-b}{6-a-2b}\binom 2 b \cdot \frac{6!}{a!(2!)^b}$$

Evaluating the formula ...

$$ \begin{eqnarray*} 
N_{tot} =&  \binom 2 2 \binom 2 2 \frac{6!}{(2!)^2} 
+ \binom 2 1 \binom 2 2 \frac{6!}{(2!)^2} 
+ \binom 3 3 \binom 2 1 \frac{6!}{ 2!}
\\+ &\binom 2 0 \binom 2 2 \frac{6!}{2! (2!)^2}  
+ \binom 3 2 \binom 2 1 \frac{6!}{ 2! (2!)} 
+ \binom 4 4 \binom 2 0 \frac{6!}{ 2! } 
\\+ & \binom 3 1 \binom 2 1 \frac{6!}{ 3! (2!)} 
+ \binom 4 3 \binom 2 0 \frac{6!}{ 3! } 
\end{eqnarray*}$$
$$ =(1)(1)(180)+(2)(1)(180)+(1)(2)(360)+ (1)(1)(90) \\+ (3)(2)(180) + (1)(1)(360) + (3)(2)(60) +(4)(1)(120)   $$

$$ =180+360+720+90+1080+360+360+480   = 3630$$

Comment: I like your methodology, but I do not believe this works. You fail to count the number of ways the *extra* numbers could appear. For example, in the case that there are $3$ $1$'s and no pairs, your formula gives $120$, but I calculated it as being $324$.

Comment: The way I thought of it for the specific case mentioned above, you are choosing groups of $6$ from $[1,1,1,2,3,4,5]$). If you take it case-by-case, there are $4$ ways of making a group of $6$ with the $1$'s together (like $[a,1,1,1,b,c] $), $12$ ways of doing it with a two $1$'s together (like $[1,a,1,1,b,c] $), and $2$ ways for all three ones to be separated (like $[1,a,1,b,1,c] $). For each of these cases, there are $3(3!)$ ways to choose and permute the other three numbers in the list. This leads to $(4 + 12 + 2)(3!)3 = 324$

Comment: @infinitylord  - I see that I am mistaken for the reason you mention. But I am suspicious of the 324 number - I really think it should be 4(120)=480 like john gets

Comment: I would be quite surprised if it is not $324$, as I did it brute force. I'll provide a little more detail and see if you spot a mistake in my method. (Sorry, I'm about to add a couple more comments here)

Comment: **grouping three ones**: $[1,1,1,a,b,c], [a,1,1,1,b,c], [a,b,1,1,1,c], [a,b,c,1,1,1] $

Comment: **grouping two ones:** $[1,1,a,*,*,*]$. The one can go in any of the starred spots, so there are $3$ groups like this. $[a,1,1,b,*,*] \implies 2$ groups, $[*,a,1,1,b,*] \implies 2$ groups. $[*,*,*,a,1,1] \implies 3$ groups. This males for a total of $12$

Comment: **grouping no ones:** $ [1,a,1,b,1,c], [a,1,b,1,c,1]$ are the only possibilities

Comment: In each case, the extra numbers could be $(2,3,4), (2,3,5), (3,4,5) $ and there are $3! = 6$ ways to permute them for each 3-tuple. This implies the answer is $18*3*6 = 324$

Comment: @infinitylord There are two more "grouping no ones" cases: $[1,a,b,1,c,1], [1,a,1,b,c,1]$. That completes the $20$ arrangements.

Comment: @John: You are correct thank you. However this then only amounts to $20 * 18 = 360$ combinations. It still doesn't add up to the $480$ as WW1 says you got.

Comment: @infinitylord I may have divided the cases up differently than you did but my answer attempts to explain how I arrived at the numbers (cases 4 and 5). I broke the three-ones cases up by with pair and without pair.

Comment: @infinitylord actually there is one more set of "extra numbers" (2, 4, 5) - this puts us in agreement at 480

Comment: @WW1: Care to elaborate? I'd like to what they are

Comment: @infinitylord the extra numbers could be $(2,3,4),(2,3,5),(3,4,5)$ and
$(2,4,5)$ so there are $\binom 43 = 4$ of these.
Your calculation for the case with three "1"''s and three singles becomes $20*4*6=480$